# Downloading files using checkboxes in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have created a model using Django & am displaying its contents in form of a table on a HTML page. Each row of this table has download links for different files. I have also added a checkbox to each row of this table. I want to create a download button which will download the files corresponding to those rows whose checkboxes have been ticked [image: see the screenshot to get a visual idea of the table that I have]. Is it possible to do this using django alone or do I need to use something else like jquery?